# Read data using from the device as soon as an app opens in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, sharedpreferences

I am saving the app's theme to the device using SharedPreferences, in this way:

```
void _serializeTheme() async {
    SharedPreferences _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _preferences.setString("theme", "dark");
}
```

Upon opening the app I can use `_preferences.getString("theme")` to detect the theme, but as `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` is async, I need to wrap the home of my application in a `FutureBuilder` which waits for the theme to load before displaying the page and renders a container while waiting. My problem is that for the brief time that the app spends loading the theme the screen flashes with the color of the container which, as I have no idea of which theme the user has saved before loading it, has to be a fixed color which may be in discordance with the background color of the home page. To prevent this is there a way I can load the theme before displaying anything at all?

So, is there a way to run an asyncronous function before opening the application? Or if this isn't fiesable, is there a way to read data syncronously from the device so that I could read it inside `initState()` so that I can know the theme that the user saved before rendering anyting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would get await data in before runApp(),
Example:

```
main()async{
// Here 
SharedPreferences _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

   runApp(YourApp());
    
}
```

or

```
void main() {
  runZonedGuarded(() async {
// Here 
SharedPreferences _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

   runApp(YourApp());
    
  }, (_, s) {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to show *something*.  You can set a splash screen of your choice using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash, and then use that same screen to show when the FutureBuilder doesn't yet have the completed future, before transitioning to your main theme when it's ready.